# Boost bind with asio::placeholders::error

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind, boost-asio

Why it doesn't work?

--- boost_bind.cc ---

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

void func1 (const int& i)
{ }

void func2 (const ::asio::error_code& e)
{ }

int main ()
{
    ::boost::function<void()> f1 = ::boost::bind (&func1, 1);

    // it doesn't work!
    ::boost::function<void()> f2 = ::boost::bind (&func2, ::asio::placeholders::error);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
while_true@localhost:~> g++ -lpthread boost_bind.cc -o boost_bind
In file included from boost_bind.cc:2:
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::_bi::list1::operator()(boost::_bi::type, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(const asio::error_code&), A = boost::_bi::list0, A1 = boost::arg (*)()]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::_bi::result_traits::type boost::_bi::bind_t::operator()() [with R = void, F = void (*)(const asio::error_code&), L = boost::_bi::list1 (*)()>]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:152:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker0::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t (*)()> >, R = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:904:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function0::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t (*)()> >, R = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:720:   instantiated from ‘boost::function0::function0(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t (*)()> >, R = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1040:   instantiated from ‘boost::function::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t (*)()> >, R = void]’
boost_bind.cc:14:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:232: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘a[boost::_bi::storage1 (*)()>::a1_ [with int I = 1]]’
while_true@localhost:~>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write `boost::asio::placeholders::error` instead of `::asio::placeholders::error`. Also, I don't understand the purpose of `::` you have in front of the `boost` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want boost::system::error_code:

```
void func2 (const boost::system::error_code& error)
{ }
```

and also this:

```
::boost::function<void(boost::system::error_code&)> f2 = ::boost::bind (&func2, boost::asio::placeholders::error);
```

I find asio's placeholder stuff too verbose, so I'd write this instead:

```
::boost::function<void(boost::system::error_code&)> f2 = ::boost::bind (&func2, _1);
```

Comment: Does it make sense?

---
void func1 (const int& i) { }
void func2 (const boost::system::error_code& e) { }

boost::function<void()> f1 = boost::bind (&func1, 1);
boost::function<void()> f2 = boost::bind(&func2, asio::placeholders::error);
---

if the first bind works, why the second one does not?

Comment: in libasio-doc/asio/examples/http/client/async_client.cpp we have the type asio::error_code and the parameter asio::placeholders::error, and it works.

Comment: You must be using an old version of boost, < v1.35, right?  My response assumed 1.35 or later where system::error_code is used instead of asio::error_code.  I tested my answer with v1.38, ymmv.

Comment: I was using v1.34. Now I'm using v1.42, and I'm trying to compile your code. It works, but I can't run the function f. It seems boost::asio::placeholders::error can't be used as an argument of type boost::system::error_code&, but why? Even async_client.cpp sample found inside the package we have it.

Comment: Look:

---
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

void func (const boost::system::error_code& error)
{ }

int main ()
{
  boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> f = boost::bind (&func, _1);

  // this doesn't work!
  f (boost::asio::placeholders::error);

  return 0;
}
---

Comment: boost::asio::placeholders::error is used for bind, you want to pass in an actual boost::system::error_code object there.

Comment: I just didn't underestand why it may be used as in async_client.cpp and it can't be used in my example. In my example, "boost::function<void()> f1 = boost::bind (&func1, 1)" works. as expected, boost::bind(&func1, 1) resolves to a function that returns void and doesn't receive any argument. In async_client.cpp, asio::placeholders::error is used in a bind as an argument for a function that receives const asio::error_code&, and it works!